# How to see the execution plan of a multi-statement table valued function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-execution-plan

I have a view in SQL Server that calls a function. When I show the *actual execution plan* for querying the view, what happens inside the function is completely opaque though.

As a small example, I made a function called `MyFunction`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION MyFunction 
    (@lower int, @upper int)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE 
                     (
                         [Id] int,
                         [Value] int
                     )
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE 
                       (
                           [Id] int,
                           [Value] int
                       )

    INSERT INTO @SomeTable
        SELECT EE.Id, M.[ID, Bolag1]
        FROM DataModel.EconomicEstate AS EE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DataModel.Metadata AS M ON M.[ID, Kstn] = EE.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DataModel.Metadata AS M2 ON M2.[Period] = M.[Period]

    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
        SELECT [Id], [Value]
        FROM @SomeTable
        WHERE [Value] >= @lower AND [Value] <= @upper

    RETURN
END
```

And a view called `MyView` that calls `MyFunction`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW MyView
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM MyFunction(200000, 400000)
GO
```

Next, I query the view:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Id], [Value]
FROM 
    [Test].[dbo].[MyView]
```

But in the actual execution plan, in SQL Server Management Studio, this is all I see:

[image: Actual Execution Plan in SQL Server]

Is it possible to dig deeper into `MyFunction` to see the performance it uses for joining the tables together? Can I somehow analyze the performance of a multi-statement table valued function?

Comment: Interesting that the timings don't even seem correct either - that it took 0ms to insert 4.4 million rows into the table variable doesn't seem credible. I guess just have to assume 277 ms (934-657). I would just run it independently of the view. I think you would have to use some mechanism for gathering actual execution plans such as profiler or extended events otherwise

Comment: Nothing in your function indicates you need it, why not just just do it in the view, or inline function if that's your game, this way you will see how the QP look

Comment: @MartinSmith The query took about 40 seconds to run, so I don't know why it says 0.934 seconds in the execution plan. How do I run the function independently of the view? If I just run the query `SELECT  * FROM MyFunction(200000, 400000)`, it shows the same execution plan without any details about what happens inside `MyFunction`.

Comment: @siggemannen It's just a small example. My actual function, whose performance I want to diagnose, is much larger.

Comment: Ok, then i think you're screwed :D If you enable SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON; do you see anything?

Comment: @siggemannen No, it prints very little additional information.

Comment: If you move the function code to regular procedure with params, you should be able to see what it does, and it should be pretty much the same. Sure, there's some overhead and perhaps it's not as good at sniffing up the parameters but the query plans should be similar. I'm guessing it choses bad plans

Comment: Ah I misremembered and thought selecting from it directly would give you a more informative plan.  - you could just capture actual execution plans with an appropriate XEvent session https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/using-xevents-to-capture-an-actual-execution-plan/ba-p/392136  If it is taking 40 seconds then you can start the query off and run `select * from sys.dm_exec_query_statistics_xml(session_id_of_other_session)` in another window to see if that gives you the live plan

Comment: That table function can't be inlined and has to be executed before the rest of the query can be processed. The performance is bad by definition. The optimizer for the *outer* query only knows it will receive a table variable with unknown statistics.

Comment: Ah the unexpectedly low timings could be because of the Interleaved Execution feature with multi statement TVFs - so you only see the timings for the plan after the deferred compile.

Comment: which version of `SQL Server`?

Comment: Is your query using batch mode perhaps - in batch mode the timings are per operator, not cumulative.

Comment: This TVF can easily be replaced with an inline TVF. The two INSERT statements into the unindexed tables can be replaced with a single SELECT. More complex queries can be replaced with nested selects or CTEs, but this particular query could be a single SELECT with a WHERE

Comment: did you try [OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_INTERLEAVED_EXECUTION_TVF'))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing-details?view=sql-server-ver16#interleaved-execution-for-mstvfs)

Comment: I noticed that behavior, too. Usually one can circumvent this problem by using "Display Estimated Execution Plan" (CTRL+L), which strangely enough displays what would happen inside the UDF, while the actual execution plan remains hidden.

Comment: SSMS won't be very helpful here, I'm afraid, since it won't show plan(s) for statements inside UDFs. Plans are compiled and cached on a per-statement basis, so for your UDF you can expect to find two plans (one for each insert statement) by way of `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` and friends.